# Installing Qt5 on Arch Linux

Tags: archlinux, xorg, qtonpi

I've used pacman on Arch to install xorg-server and Qt5, but keep running into "display not found issues" or "qmlviewer cannot connect to x server" when running xhost and qmlviewer respectively.

The X11 server appears to work (I can run Xterm), but I suspect I'm taking the wrong approach to building Qt on my Pi... Do I actually need an X server to run Qt on Pi? I keep reading about how QTonPi bypasses X based rendering...

Should I uninstall xorg-server, Qt5 and attempt to build QTonPi, or can I "patch" my current installation?

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/RaspberryPi_Beginners_guide) for complee details on how to build Raspberry Pi.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646930/cannot-connect-to-x-server-0-0-with-a-qt-application) for your particular issue.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a synopsis here... link-only answers are not helpful!